# Hooking Message Proc

Tags: c++, message-queue, game-engine

I would like to hook a game's message proc, however if I use SetWindowsHookEx then I need to know the thread id. Is there anyway to find out which thread handles the message queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the id of the thread that created the window by calling [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The return value is the id of the thread.

Comment: Not typically - always. An HWND is tied to the thread that creates it, and only that thread can receive messages for that HWND.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a handle to the window, this should work:

```
DWORD threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, nullptr);
```